# Image doesn't show in Safari browser

Tags: html, css, image, safari

I have an image in a html website that works normally in Firefox, Chrome or IE but when I try with safari I shows nothing just a blank space. The image is in this link http://astrovision.us/bibliografia.php

I know there is a bug in Safari but I don't know how to fix it.

I tried to change the image format but it doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: It's **possible** that you simply haven't cleared your Safari cache. Try holding `SHIFT` while clicking on the refresh icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why safari isn't respecting `height: 100%` on the element with the background image. Seems like it's because you're using `min-height` on the parent, and not `height`. So you can change `min-height` to `height` on the parent that wraps the element with the background image...

```
.bibliografia .inner-row {
  min-height: 600px;
}
```

to

```
.bibliografia .inner-row {
  height: 600px;
}
```

---

Or you can simply move `min-height: 600px` from `.bibliografia .inner-row` to `.bibliografia .inner-row .bg_bilbiografia`

---

Or you can absolutely position `.bg_bibliografia` in it's parent

```
.bibliografia .inner-row {
  position: relative;
}
.bibliografia .inner-row .bg_bilbiografia {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i change to this: 

    .bibliografia .inner-row {
  position: relative;
}
.bibliografia .inner-row .bg_bilbiografia {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
} and now works fine!